# Protect against associative array access in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to tell the TypeScript compiler to not allow illegal access of private variables via the object map?

For example:

```
class Thing {
    private id: number;

    constructor() {
        this.id = 1
    }
}

var thing = new Thing()
alert(thing["id"]); // I want this to throw a compiler error
```

Comment: I think it *should* be an error already. But it isn't > so I'd report it as a bug. I am curious how you ended up with this scenario though :)

Comment: I've been researching TypeScript with regards to my use case. I want to use it to load other peoples scripts. But I want to force those scripts to obey the rules. If they can access a libraries private variable then it isn't going to work :) Are you sure it's a bug? I was reading this blog http://tedpatrick.com/2013/06/25/7-months-with-typescript/ and he mentions he uses the associative array to get around compiler problems. This is why I asked the question, because i don't want that to be allowed.

Comment: Protecting against intentionally-invasive external scripts isn't something TypeScript does. In general it's nearly impossible to do that kind of thing safely; if you do not trust an external script, do not run it in the same execution context as your own code.

Comment: It is something it can do. But i'm guessing from your response and from reading around about TypeScript, TS is meant to support normal javascript code. If this is the case then a switch will never be added to force this behaviour.

But then why does the compiler have an argument to force an error when types cannot be inferred? var a; will fail compilation. I want a similar argument --strictTypes or something like that disables old javascript. I may be wishing for too much ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an inconsistency, although it may turn out to be by design.

In the example below, the compiler determines the type of variable `b`, but ignores the fact it is private. To be consistent, it should either:

- Not infer the type, or
- Infer the type *and* check access

Obviously in your case you are after the second of these options.

```
class Example {
    private private: number;
    public public: number;

    constructor() {
        this.private = 1
    }
}

var example = new Example()

var a = example.private; // Error
var b = example["private"]; // number
var c = example["other"]; // any 
var d = example["public"]; // number
```

I have raised an [issue for this on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1680).